# NSString encoding for accents displays crazy characters

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, encoding, nsstring

I am downloading data (text) from a server.

I have tried with both:`NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` and `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

But I keep seeing things like: `{"estado":"M\u00e9xico"}`

Noting that it should read `México` and not `M\u00e9xico` (with an accent over the e).

Looking online I figured that `\u00e9` is in fact `é` [link.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm)

But the NSString is not able to interpret this and instead prints weird things on my UILabels:

[image]

I would really really appreciate your help on this.

Alsso, if you are itnerested, you can download the data from here: http://www.miorden.com/demo/iphone/estadoJSON.php

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.miorden.com/demo/iphone/estadoJSON.php"]];

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Downloaded: %@", string);    

string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.miorden.com/demo/iphone/estadoJSON.php"] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"Downloaded: %@", string);
```

I have been literally trying for days and it is killing me!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Comment: I have tried UTF8 with no better results, when accessing the URL directly from the browser I also see the weird characters. But when I try it using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) I can see everything correctly, what else might me wrong? What code would you use? NSData to NSString, NSString directly?

Comment: What HTTP content encoding header is the PHP setting? If you don't know you can check the header values with a debugger tool/plugin. Changing it may help if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is in JSON format, so you'll need to JSON decode it too.

For example using this: https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.miorden.com/demo/iphone/estadoJSON.php"]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsArray:data error:&error];

NSLog(@"Test: %@", [[array objectAtIndex:11] valueForKey:@"estado"]);
```

outputs

```
2011-08-11 09:35:45.742 enctest[63236:407] Test: México
```

Comment: The problem is the encoding, the parsing is not a problem but thank you for the help.

Comment: Don't think so. What JSON decoder are you using? I added some code sample above that works for me.

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be unicode, try NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: I just opened it in TextWrangler (the source doc) and it appears to be escaped. Does it ever appear properly when you view it? I think the server is escaping it in the output.

Comment: When I open it on my browser I see the codes too. Do you think its a problem with the php code then? Do you have any suggestions, I can modify the php, right now its just retrieving from the database and JSON ecoding it.